# How to change default font size in rich:editor

Tags: richfaces

I have a rich:editor field in my xhtml view and it has a default font size of 11. It is like this:

```
<rich:editor id="editor_value"
    configuration="#{editorBean.currentSimpleConfiguration}"
    width="560" height="130" viewMode="#{editorBean.viewMode}"
    value="#{bean.value}">
```

I want to change the default font size and make it bigger.

I know that I can do this using "f:param" like:

```
<rich:editor id="editor_value"
    configuration="#{editorBean.currentSimpleConfiguration}"
    width="560" height="130" viewMode="#{editorBean.viewMode}"
    value="#{bean.value}"/>
    <f:param name="font_size" value="13px"/>
</rich:editor>
```

or putting the assignation "font_size=13px" in my "simple.properties" file (which is referenced in "configuration="#{editorBean.currentSimpleConfiguration}"")

But these solutions are not valid and the font size continues being 11px...

Anyone knows where am I wrong?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the config facet and follow CKEditor instructions : http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Example :

```
<rich:editor value="Test de contenu">
    <f:facet name="config">
    contentsCss: '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/rich.css',
    toolbar: 'custom',
    language: 'fr',
    startupFocus: true,
    toolbar_custom:
        [
            { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
            { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'
                     ,'Iframe' ] },
                    '/',
            { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
            { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
            { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] }
        ]
    </f:facet>
</rich:editor>
```

And create your custom content css :

```
body,
p
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped me at least.  the lack of good richface examples is disturbing ;(

Answer (score 0):

Just add `content_css` parameter to your `<rich:editor>` and point it to your style sheet and define your styles in it.

```
<rich:editor>
   <f:param name="content_css" value="resources/myStyles.css"/>
</rich:editor>
```

Now define your styles in **myStyles.css** as below.

```
body {
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

For more info : http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php